# Return A Path from multiple point in Geomesa

Tags: line, java, geotools, geomesa

I am trying to visualise the historic of a vehicle in a specific area , I am writing now a query to get all points off a this vehicle in this area with this :

```
    FeatureStore feature = (FeatureStore) dataStore.getFeatureSource("testone");
    SimpleFeatureSource source=dataStore.getFeatureSource("testone");
    SimpleFeatureCollection collection=source.getFeatures(CQL.toFilter("vehicleId = my_Id and DWITHIN(geom,myPointofInterest,200,meters)"));
    System.out.println(collection.size());
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            // Here i will create the Polyline 
            System.out.println(iterator.next());

        }
```

is there a function in geomesa that aggregate points into one Polyline so i can do it in geomesa not in my server ? 
and for the visualisation , a vehicle can enter this area and leave it and re enter again , do you have any idea how can I detect this multiple Path ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMesa uses GeoTools and JTS as geospatial and geometry libraries, respectively.  With the observations, you can build a LineString [1] and visualize that.  If you can detect when the path leaves the area, you could build a MultiLineString instead.

[1] http://javadox.com/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/GeometryFactory.html#createLineString(com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate[])

Comment: I tried this approach but I am having another probleme :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Points of LinearRing do not form a closed linestring
I think the LineString Should be closed

Comment: LineString must end with the starting point , it's not a path

Comment: LineStrings should not have to be a closed ring.  Are you calling createLineString?  There are methods which will make a LinearRing and those do need to be closed.

Comment: yes I am calling createLineString from GeometryFactory